# ScalaTest Maven configuration show time measures for each test

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I want to print time measures for each test. There is a way to do it using SBT - http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt

However looking at this page - http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin I can't figure out what to add to pom.xml so every test will show it's duration.

I want to configure this inside pom.xml so my teammates will not have to run maven with special flags. I don't know if this one even possible so a negative answer will do as well :)

Here is a part of the pom.xml configuring ScalaTest:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>ProductionCommons.txt</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the single-letter configuration parameters in front of your filename for your file reporter. In the example it is:

```
<filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
```

These config params are described here:

[http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.5/index.html#org.scalatest.tools.Runner$@configuringReporters](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.3/index.html#org.scalatest.tools.Runner%24@configuringReporters)

The one you want is the D, which enables the durations to be printed out, so:

```
<filereports>D ProductionCommons.txt</filereports>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wonder if it's possible to see the durations during Maven test run and not after it's done in the file.

Comment: For future users - The link is dead. Try this: https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.9/org/scalatest/tools/Runner$.html